# Is there any rule of grammar/usage for "que si" and "que acaso" when they start a question?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**¿Hay alguna regla de gramática/uso para «que si» y «que acaso» cuando empiezan una frase?**

**Details in English:**

I recently came across a test question similar to the following:

> **—Usted tendrá mucho dinero que contar, ¿no es así?**
>   **—¿Que si/acaso tengo dinero?**

The correct answer was:

> **—¿Que si tengo dinero?**

Why?

Thanks in advance.

**Detalles en español:**

Hace poco me encontré con una pregunta de examen similar a la siguiente:

> **—Usted tendrá mucho dinero que contar, ¿no es así?**
>   **—¿Que si/acaso tengo dinero?**

La respuesta correcta era:

> **—¿Que si tengo dinero?**

¿Por qué?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondo en español; si algo no se entiende lo puedo traducir al inglés.

La lógica detrás de *¿Que si...?* es la misma que la de otras frases interrogativas que repiten lo que el interlocutor acaba de decir. Esta repetición o eco se utiliza para expresar sorpresa o para contestar afirmativamente con un tono irónico, enfático o condescendiente. Lo que se repite es una frase o proposición como una unidad, y para esto se utiliza *que* porque *que* indica una proposición subordinada.

Supongamos que la afirmación original fuera:

> *—Usted tiene dinero de sobra.*

Entonces la respuesta-eco sería (con tono de sorpresa o indignación):

> *—¿Que tengo dinero de sobra?*

Esto es básicamente equivalente a

> *—¿**Estás diciendo** que tengo dinero de sobra?*
>   *—¿**En serio afirmas** que tengo dinero de sobra?*

o algo similar.

En el caso de *¿Que si...?*, lo que ocurre es que la afirmación original termina con una pregunta de sí/no (*¿no es así?*). La forma de referirse en el discurso indirecto a una pregunta de sí/no es precediéndola con *si* (al igual que en inglés se precede con *if* o mejor con *whether*).

Supongamos que la afirmación terminase con una pregunta retórica de sí/no. Las alternativas son variadas pero en general sería así:

> *—A usted le sobra el dinero, ¿no?*
>   *—A usted le sobra el dinero, ¿no es así?*
>   *—A usted le sobra el dinero, ¿verdad?*

En este caso se puede responder de cualquiera de estas tres maneras:

> *—¿Que me sobra el dinero?*
>   *—¿Que si me sobra el dinero?*
>   *—¿Si me sobra el dinero?*

Es decir que el *¿que si...?* no tiene nada de especial. No es una estructura gramatical particular. Es sólo una manera de hacerse eco de una proposición que incluye una pregunta de sí/no.

Por otra parte, *¿que acaso...?* no me suena correcto para nada (para comenzar una respuesta-eco como éstas de las que estamos hablando). *Acaso* no cumple la misma función que *si*, aunque a veces aparezcan asociados (se pueden usar juntos para enfatizar lo hipotético de una condición: *si acaso...*).

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by Pablo.  I want to add something that will not fit well in a comment.

Say you are conversing with someone but he is not expressing himself very clearly.  He asks you a question and you guess at what he's getting at.  You might say,

> Whether I have health insurance?  Is that what you're asking?

That's "Que si."  Which is short for

> ¿Ud. me está preguntando *que si* tengo seguro de salud?

---

One can certainly begin a question with "acaso":

> ¿Acaso no me crees?

Meaning

> Perhaps [or Maybe] you don't believe me?

It's a bit of a challenge.  A bit aggressive/in your face.

(That's not the only thing one can do with *acaso*, but it's the only thing I can think of for the beginning of a question.)

There is no reason to put "que" in front of "acaso."

Comment: It _was_ a great answer by Pablo and I'm glad I took the time to go over it with a fine-toothed comb and really try to get the most out of his post.  However, you also gave a great answer, aparente001.  I can't give you both a green checkmark, but I can give you an upvote, and I did.